# How to find this text in a string and extract it?

Tags: php, regex

So I have a string:

```
$string = "blah blah blah [image=cat.jpg] blah blahblah";
```

`$string` is user input so it could be anything, in other words I just want to get the part between the `"[image=" and the "]"` in `$string` and store it in a variable like:

```
$src = "cat.jpg";
```

Thanks, hope this question is clear, probably a regex question I feel.

this is what i tried:

```
$string = "blah blah blah [image=cat.jpg] blah blahblah";
$reg = '/\[image=\]/i';
preg_match_all($reg, $string, $matches);
$src = $matches[1][0];
```

Comment: At [so] you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/)**.

Comment: If you say it's a regex question, what patterns have you tried?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you look into [Regex](https://regex101.com/)?

Comment: @Kaiwen In order to reopen this question, I think you need to do more. When you tried your code, tell us what happened? What was your expected result, and what actually happened? Please give [mcve] another read, and help us help you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$string = "blah blah blah [image=cat.jpg] blah blahblah";
$reg = '/\[image=(.*)\]/i';
preg_match_all($reg, $string, $matches);
$src = $matches[1][0];
```

Comment: Don't answer questions that is unclear and/or is missing own efforts from OP

Comment: @Andreas This question is pretty clear. Not much effort but clear.

Comment: Also this pattern will fail in a real world example.

Comment: @Eric but it has no attempts from OP. And the answer has no explanation. Unbelievable that people upvote. J.Litvak you should include an explanation. Your answers are more or less always without explanation

Comment: @Andreas Believe it or not, many popular questions had no effort done on the OP's end.

Comment: And they are probably old questions. Generally questions that has no effort gets closed (like this one did). @Eric